# Angular HttpClient proxy

Tags: angular

Is there any way to set proxy for Angular 7 HttpClient request? Not angular cli but just simple HttpClient, e.g. if I want to forward several requests through postman or just use proxy after I deployed the web.

Comment: The proxy occurs on the server side, in the webpack server bundled with CLI. It doesn't actually work at the HttpClient level. You'd need to write [an interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) to do that, or just change a configuration setting for that matter.

Comment: I'm fine with any solution, how can I do it with an interceptor? I didn't find any samples or even mentions of "proxy" within @angular package. Should I set headers manually?
E.g. I have intranet web and I need to send several requests through the internal proxy. There are no webpacks in that case, application is already packed and deployed.

Comment: Typically, corporate proxies are invisible to the user; the proxy is set up at the browser or OS level and requests made by the browser (e.g., those made by HttpClient) run normally. If you want to bypass that proxy, you need to do it at that level.

Comment: What about postman and fiddler in cases when it's impossible to serve the app?